# How to destructure variable into function's parameter?

Tags: swift

How can I pass the value of all key from object as functions parameters? like python did.
I have one function `getNameInfo` with parameter with default value `firstName, lastName, age` and one object with key `firstName, lastName, age` how is the best way for me to descture the pbject and pass all value of key into function? in python i can do something like `getNameInfo(**a.__dict__.values())` but

```
class Person {
    public var firstName = "firstName"
    public var lastName = "lastName"
    public var age = 12
  
    public init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int){
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.age = age
    
  }
  
}
let a = Person(firstName: "firstName", lastName: "lastName", age: 12)
func getNameInfo(firstName: String = "i am first", lastName: String = "I am lat", age: Int = 50) {
  print("\(fName), \(lName), \(age)")
}
getNameInfo()
// getNameInfo(a) // expect to print out firstName, lastName, 12
```

Comment: Don't try to do Python things in Swift. How about changing `getNameInfo` to take a `Person` instead?

Comment: 2 things: 1) `getNameInfo` doesn't just return "name info", since it includes the age. Perhaps `summary` is a better name. 2) This should just be a computed property on the `Person` class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no similar feature in Swift. The closest version is to use protocols:

```
protocol NameInfoProviding {
    var firstName: String { get }
    var lastName: String { get }
    var age: Int { get }
}

extension Person: NameInfoProviding {}

func getNameInfo(_ nameInfo: some NameInfoProviding) {
    print("\(nameInfo.firstName), \(nameInfo.lastName), \(nameInfo.age)")
}
getNameInfo(a)
```

But yes, this is a different feature and used in different ways.